# Multiple Webservices With Common Operations and Types

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

I have received many WSDLs that have common operations (login, logout, insert, update etc) and common types (request, response, connect fault, data container). The differences that i found are target namespace and type of data being transported within the data container. Is it possible to have one service client that exposes the common operations?

Comment: in theory yes... although the fact the payload differs in type would make rather problematic... what is the goal ? a "unified proxy" ?

Comment: yes, i would like to create an abstract base client

Comment: it is possible but you will to implement everything from scratch esp. since they differ in types etc.

Answer (score 2):

Only if their interfaces and schemas match exactly. And they don't, since the namespace differs, for one, so no.

Why would you do that? You could however create a kind of wrapper that calls recurring methods on the various service proxy clients.

Edit: I mean like this:

```
public void Login(String username, String password)
{
    _client1.Login(username, password);
    _client2.Login(username, password);
    _client3.Login(username, password);
}
```

You don't want to create a "universal" client, for it'll be unable to communicate with one of the services you're trying to consume when the signature of that service changes. What do you do then, create a second client? Then you're back to square one.

Comment: Could you give an example of the wrapper?

Comment: I don't get how the above code would work and how it should help with the above problem.

Comment: Then I don't know what your problem is. Explaining it more detailed, perhaps with code you have now and how you want it to be.

Comment: Actually you do know, as you stated above, i want to create a universal client. The service provider issues the WSDLS with same structure for many many years now. And if something would change we'll decide later on.